# Visual Studio extension - Inheritance class diagram

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, uml

In Visual studio 2013, we have an option to "view the class diagram" for a **single** project where it shows the inheritance relationships(hierarchy).

In my application, I have base classes in one project & derived classes in another.
Is there any extension that can automatically generate the class diagram with inheritance relationship among multiple projects?

Answer (score 2):

Old question but it could still be relevant for others.

There's a Visual Studio extension called **Quick Diagram** that can generate type inheritance diagrams that are not limited to a single project. The types can be anywhere in the solution, in any project (in source code or in referenced metadata).

It can be found here: [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FerencVizkeleti.QuickDiagramToolforC)

It's free, open source. However it does not support VS2013 only VS2015.